# Does Android support slow-motion video playback?

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer

I need to make video player on Android that is able to play in slow motion and with different playback speeds. I still cannot find a native API or some code to do this. Does Android 2.2 - 2.3 support to video slow-motion and can we control the video playback speed?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/68faac2c99db7b96

Comment: I face same problem . Is above ans helped you ?

Comment: @ Yoesoff did you find the solution? I am also trying to play a video in slow motion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, from API **23** android has [PlaybackParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/PlaybackParams.html) class .It supports adjustment of playback speed of video briefly given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45613064/5996106) .

Answer (score 2):

You can try exploring libVLC for this. VLC player for Android is almost due. Check their website.

Check this thread that discusses how you do it.. http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=89296

[libVLC developer documentation here](http://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial)  with normal playback sample. You need to modify this sample to play the video frame by frame or slow down the frame rate.