# How to change camera frame rate to create slow motion or time lapse video in Android

Tags: android, parameters, camera, frame-rate, mediarecorder

I have a class setup that now gives me a preview on my surface view and allows me to record a video file. I would like to increase the FPS to create a slow motion video and decrease the FPS to create a time lapse video. I have tried using recorder.setVideoFrameRate() and ensured I call it in the right sequence but I just keep getting illegal state exceptions when ever I try to alter any settings on the recording.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or an example on how to effectively control the settings for the camera?

Cheers.

Comment: Not possible because slow motion is only achieved with high speed cameras :)

Comment: Can the camera not record at a higher FPS and then keep playback at a lower FPS? I know some of the default camera apps on phones like the HTC Sensation Xe have a slow motion option. 

Also, do you know how you could achieve time lapse by reducing the FPS considerably or taking images and constructing a video file from them?

Comment: By default most of the mobile cameras record the movie at MAX of 30fps. And frame rate is a hardware thing not software so you can't record the movie greater than the camera MAX frame rate.

Comment: One thing you can do is to play the movie at slow frame rate, for example if you play a 30 FPS movie at 15 FPS then it will slow down it to 50%. To achieve this you need to use some video play back library with slow down feature just like VLC. More info you can find here :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618239/does-android-support-slow-motion-video-playback

Comment: @ScottHelme did you found a way to do this? I'm afraid the solution of the player won't be enough for a problem I got.

Comment: @AldoReyes not yet :-(...

Comment: I see, well I think I'm going to give it a try by compiling ffmpeg for android and see what I can do with it.

Comment: Let me know how it goes, I would be interested to find out!

Comment: Has somebody found any solution?

Comment: Hello, does somebody know an android third application which really capture at 120 fps? even if it require high hardware or specifics phones?