# Using VLC's MediaPlayer in my Android application

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, libvlc, vlc-android

I've been struggling for days to build an application that, given a RTSP link, views the video to the screen.

It's a live video streaming coming from an IP camera in H264 format (it's not a file).

I couldn't get it done using the native MediaPlayer or VideoView (it starts showing the video and then freezes afrer 2-3 seconds), but since that when I view it in VLC player it's working fine, I've decided to use a VLC MedaPlayer in my application.

I've found some sources such as vlc-android and exoplayer_vlc, but I would like just to have a library jar, which I get import to my application and just use its classes. Is there such a jar somewhere? How can I make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073970/how-to-embed-vlc-media-player-to-my-android-app

Comment: hey....can you post the link which you had mentioned here,..
let me check that once

Comment: @gvsharma what do you mean?