# How to embed VLC media player to Android Application?

Tags: android, vlc

I have a video streaming Camera (from RTSP) and I cannot play its stream on my regular videoview in android. So i need to embed vlc player in to my app.Any one knows proper steps to integrate vlc player to my app..?

I already saw this link [How to embed VLC media player to my Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073970/how-to-embed-vlc-media-player-to-my-android-app) , It was not work properly for me

Answer (score 1):

VlC source code is avialable [Here](https://github.com/mstorsjo/vlc-android)
You can also use vitamio for playing RTSP, I have used it and it working for me.
Check [this](https://www.vitamio.org/en/)

Comment: vitamio is properietary. We need open source.In the case of android-vlc it shows error like this **vlc/vlc.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.**

Comment: you need to compile vlc

Comment: try this link https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/ 
you need a ubuntu system to compile it