# How to build LibVLC for Android

Tags: android, libvlc

I am trying to compile the libVLC so that I can use the VLC library for RTSP viewing on Android TV.

Here are the logs from the current execution.

```
libmysofa-0.5.tar.gz: OK337175/396660)   
touch .sum-mysofa
  2 6090k    2  172k    0     0  11160      0  0:09:18  0:00:15  0:09:03     0
curl: (18) transfer closed with 6059638 bytes remaining to read
make: *** [../../contrib/tarballs/libarchive-3.3.2.tar.gz] Error 18
make: *** Deleting file `../../contrib/tarballs/libarchive-3.3.2.tar.gz'
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Resolving deltas: 100% (396660/396660), done.
From http://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
contribs: make fetch failed
```

Comment: follow this: https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/

Comment: followed the link wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile the error is after following the link.

Comment: Looks like a connection issue.

Comment: follow my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60881819/6147653