# I am building an app which support all formats (ex: avi, flv, mp4, mkv). currently i am using exoplayer but it so not support all formats

Tags: android, video, exoplayer

I am building an app that supports all video formats(ex: avi, flv, mp4, mkv).
Currently, I am using Exoplayer but it does not support all video formats.
Some apps in the play store support almost all video formats. like Mx Player, inshot video player.
How these apps are playing so many video formats???
what can I do to play all the video formats??

I have tried but I do not found any answer.

Answer (score 0):

If ExoPlayer does not support the formats you need, VLC may be a good choice.

It is not as natively integrated into Android but it does have wide support for Android and there is and Android build and sample available.

You can test playback with the app from PlayStore first or from here: https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android

See this thread for examples of how to integrate into your app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60881819/334402

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will VLC.